# Why my contains and replace method doesn't work right?

Tags: java, string, replace, contains

I was trying to make something then i couldn't write an if method with contains and replace method. What was i missing?

```
   import java.util.Scanner;
public class replacesomething
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner cumle = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the sentence u want to replace ");
        String str1 = cumle.next();
        if (str1.contains("replace"))
        {
            str1.replace("replace", "Hi");
            System.out.println("Replaced Sentence: " + str1);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Sentence doesn't contains that...");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Strings are *immutable* in Java. You can't change them. All methods that "modify" a `String` ... don't. They return a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the replace method call to:

```
str1 = str1.replace("replace", "Hi");
```

Since `String` are immutable, you need to reassign the result back to `str1`. It doesn't perform in-place replacement, rather it constructs and returns a new String object. the original String is unmodified.

Comment: Thank you i got it but if i write "replace and something else" it prints "Hi" only. How can i do it for one word instead of all sentence? I mean, I want to print "Hi and something else".

Answer (score 3):

Strings are immutable in Java; you can't edit them once created. Instead, the "replace" method returns an new string. If you assign str1 with the result of replace you will get the result you expect.

Comment: Thank you i got it but if i write "replace and something else" it prints "Hi" only. How can i do it for one word instead of all sentence? I mean, I want to print "Hi and something else".